# Which property of CSS not allowing fixed header to overlay scrolled element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have designed a fixed header for my `html table`. Now when I am scrolling down the page everything is getting overlapped by fixed header except one `slider(noUiSlider)`. I want to know which property of `css` not allowing header to overlay this slider.

Css for fixed header :

```
 #header-fixed { 
            position: fixed; 
            top: 0px; display:none;
            background-color:white;
        }
```

JS for fixed header:

```
var tableOffset = $("#listView-tab").offset().top;
    //var $header = $("#listView-tab > thead").clone();
    var $fixedHeader = $( "#header-fixed" );

    $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
        var offset = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (offset >= tableOffset && $fixedHeader.is(":hidden")) {
            $fixedHeader.show();
        }
        else if (offset < tableOffset) {
            $fixedHeader.hide();
        }
    });
```

In the attached screen First Image shows all the element associated with the slider.
In the second screen except slider all other element gets overlapped.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could try to set the z-index of one element higher then the other

Comment: z-index for #header-fixed ?

Comment: Try to add z-index: 9999; to your #header-fixed. Should put it ontop of everything whatsoever, framework or not then.

Comment: Set them Both and find out what works best. I don't know how they relate to fixed though, but give it a shot.

Comment: Got it @randy . it worked . Could you please post the answer , you are first to reply with correct one :)

Comment: @curiousguy My answer is in the list with an example :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set the `z-index` property on your elements.

[mdn source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

The `z-index` is perfect for situations where you want elements arranged in a certain order, but you want the overlapping to be different then default.

**Example:**

```css
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
    font: 12px Arial;
}
#div1,
#div3 {
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dashed #669966;
    background-color: #ccffcc;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
#div2 {
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 170px;
    border: 1px dashed #990000;
    background-color: #ffdddd;
    text-align: center;
}
#div4 {
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    top: 65px;
    left: 50px;
    border: 1px dashed #000099;
    background-color: #ddddff;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
<br /><span class="bold">DIV #1</span>
<br />position: relative;
   <div id="div2">
   <br /><span class="bold">DIV #2</span>
   <br />position: fixed;
   <br />z-index: 1;
   </div>
</div>

<br />

<div id="div3">
<br /><span class="bold">DIV #3</span>
<br />position: relative;
   <div id="div4">
   <br /><span class="bold">DIV #4</span>
   <br />position: fixed;
   <br />z-index: 2;
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The element(s) that you want to see overlapped must have :

`z-index: 0`

The element the should be on top must have :

`z-index: 1` or higher.

Answer (score 0):

add z-index high

```
#header-fixed { 
            position: fixed; 
            top: 0px; display:none;
            background-color:white;
            z-index:999;
            }
```